# Regular expression to find text in specific Unicode range separated by spaces

Tags: regex, unicode, pcre

I'm trying to automatically wrap short Greek quotes in an English .html file with a span tag that applies a different font. In editors with full PCRE support, I can use the following expression to find a sequence of Greek words with spaces in between them:

```
([\u0370-\u03FF| ]{2,})
```

However, this simple expression will also obviously match two consecutive spaces. How can I change my regular expression so that it will match words in the specified Unicode range separated by spaces, but not two consecutive spaces?

Comment: By the way, don't use `|` inside character class, unless you want to match the vertical bar character `|` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I change my regular expression so that it will match words in the specified Unicode range separated by spaces, but not two consecutive spaces

You can use:

```
^[\u0370-\u03FF]+( [\u0370-\u03FF]+)*$
```